# need help in constructing a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create below SP but when i am trying to execute this all five parameters it is asking as input where last 3 are output parameters. can somebody point what i am messing with and how i can resolve it :

```
create PROCEDURE division_price_info_heatmap (@comp_id INT,
@compe_id INT, 
@Division_id INT out, 
@Division_name VARCHAR(20) out, 
@final_shipping_price DECIMAL(11,2) out)
AS
BEGIN
select T1.div, T1.div_n, (T1.price-T2.price)  as final_shipping_price from
(select  tcpi.division as div, td.division_name as div_n,
sum(tcpi.final_price_shipping) as price
from tb_competitor_product_info_new as tcpi 
inner join tb_division td on tcpi.division=td.division_id  
where competitor_id=@comp_id
group by tcpi.division, td.division_name
)   as T1,

(select  tcpi.division as div, td.division_name as div_n,
sum(tcpi.final_price_shipping) as price
from tb_competitor_product_info_new as tcpi 
inner join tb_division td on tcpi.division=td.division_id  
where competitor_id=@compe_id
group by tcpi.division, td.division_name
)   as T2
where T1.div=T2.div

END
```

execution command :-
division_price_info_heatmap 1,2

error :

Error: Procedure or function 'division_price_info_heatmap' expects parameter '@Division_id', which was not supplied.
SQLState:  S0004
ErrorCode: 201

I am using mssql and squirrel UI.

One more thing is it necessary for me to assign out parameters.

Comment: Can you please provide your C# code?

Comment: C# code??? it will be used in java.

Comment: i don't know anything about Java, but please also provide Java code so other people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly MS SQL doesn't use the `OUT`keyword but rather `OUTPUT`for stored procedures, try changing that part and it should work. [See this for reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

When you call the procedure you have to supply the variables that will receive the output too though like pointed out in another answer.

On a side note it looks like your not actually returning anything as you never assign anything to the output variables, but maybe that's present in code you left out.

Also, the parenthesis around the variables are not needed so the beginning of the statement should be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE division_price_info_heatmap 
  @comp_id INT,
  @compe_id INT, 
  @Division_id INT OUTPUT, 
  @Division_name VARCHAR(20) OUTPUT, 
  @final_shipping_price DECIMAL(11,2) OUTPUT
AS
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass two parameters, and the procedure requires more. The execution command should be:

```
DECLARE @Division_id INT, @Division_name VARCHAR(20), @final_shipping_price DECIMAL(11,2)
EXEC division_price_info_heatmap 1,2,@Division_id OUT,@Division_name OUT, @final_shipping_price OUT
```

or you can modify procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE division_price_info_heatmap (@comp_id INT,
@compe_id INT, 
@Division_id INT = NULL out, 
@Division_name VARCHAR(20) = NULL out, 
@final_shipping_price DECIMAL(11,2) = NULL out)
AS
...
```